# BeautifulSoup request or requests?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have a problem, when I use BeautifulSoup request:

```
 page = urlopen(url).read().decode('utf8')
 soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
 text = ' '.join(map(lambda p: p.text, soup.find_all('p')))
 return soup.title.text, text
```

I get a beautiful output like this:

```
Coronavirus: Johnson sets out 'ambitious' economic recovery plan - BBC News
*  Share this with Email Facebook Messenger Messenger Twitter Pinterest WhatsApp LinkedIn Copy this link These are external links and will open in a new window Boris Johnson has said now is the time to be "ambitious" about the UK's future, as he set out a post-coronavirus recovery plan.
* Infrastructure projects in England would be "accelerated" and there would be investment in new academy schools, green buses and new broadband, the PM added.
```

but when I use BeautifulSoup requests:

```
 page = requests.get(url)
 soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
 feed = BeautifulSoup(soup.decode('utf8'))
 text = ' '.join(map(lambda p: p.text, feed.find_all('p')))
 return soup.title.text, text
```

I get an ugly output like this:

```
Coronavirus: Johnson sets out 'ambitious' economic recovery plan - BBC News
* 

 
                    Share this with
                    
                       Email
                       
                       Facebook
                       
                       Messenger
                       
                       Messenger
                       
                       Twitter
                       
                       Pinterest
                       
                       WhatsApp
                       
                       LinkedIn
                       
                    Copy this link
                    
                    These are external links and will open in a new window
                    
             Boris Johnson has said now is the time to be "ambitious" about the UK's future, as he set out a post-coronavirus recovery plan.
* Infrastructure projects in England would be "accelerated" and there would be investment in new academy schools, green buses and new broadband, the PM added.
```

My concern is that I cannot use BeautifulSoup request as I get HTTP 403 Forbidden error, I need to use BeautifulSoup requests. How can I get the same nice looking output that I get when I use BeautifulSoup request by using BeautifulSoup requests?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you stick to `BeautifulSoup Request`, but do this to fix the HTTP 403 Forbidden Error:

```
Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I had tried headers with various values for BeautifulSoup Request but I kept getting the error due to which I had to switch to BeautifulSoup Requests.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the above problem by removing the following line of code:

```
feed = BeautifulSoup(soup.decode('utf8'))
```